# SSIS: excel connection manager unable to connect to excel 2007

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

In the Excel Connection Manager, when  I choose Excel 97-2003 to connect to an Excel(97-2003) data file as a source, I am able to see the data preview and it works fine, but when I choose Excel 2007 to connect to an Excel 2007 file, it gives the error

> Failed to connect to the Excel Connection Manager

What should I do?

Comment: Before asking your first question, it is recommended to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/Tour)

Comment: try installing `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable`, the issue may be that the excel file version is newer than 2010. Then link is provided in the first naswer

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to try:

## Installing Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable

I think that you have to install the Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable:

Download Links:

- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)
- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

## Running project in 32-bit Mode

Go to Project Configuration -> Properties -> Debugging -> Set `Run64BitRuntime` = `False`

---

## Similar Issues

The following links contains similar issues, you can refer to one of them:

- [SSIS Excel Connection Manager failed to Connect to the Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896901/ssis-excel-connection-manager-failed-to-connect-to-the-source)
- [Extracting Data From Excel with SSIS](https://mariussqlbi.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/extracting-data-from-excel-with-ssis/)