# SSIS - Excel connection fails with .xlsx

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package with data flow task where I have just Excel Source.

[image: Connection Manager]

When I am trying to connect to **.xlsx** file it fails with the following message:

[image: Fail]

> Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'.
>   Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'

There is no problem when I save this file as **.xls**. Then I can read and manipulate data. It persists with **.xlsx** files only. Any idea?

No difference whether the Run64BitRuntime is TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Lots of resources out there on this. http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/02/connecting-to-excel-xlsx-in-ssis.html

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896901/ssis-excel-connection-manager-failed-to-connect-to-the-source

Comment: Tried with both 32 and 64 bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable installed on and with Run64BitRuntime set FALSE and TRUE respectively. This not resolved the issue.

Comment: When I try to connect to this file by SQL Command I am getting the following error:
https://i.imgur.com/a0uYetg.png

Comment: Can you show us, how the data is set on the excel file?

Comment: You mean data format is the file? What is in each column?
I wouldn't say its data format related as when I save it as .xls there is no problem. Just with .xlsx files.