# SSIS Excel 2021 Import

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, version, etl

I'm trying to connect to an Excel Source, my Excel file version is 2021, but the available choices are like below (3.0 4.0 2007-2010 2013 and 2016):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBOeR.png)
so whatever the version I'm trying to choose, no one could read the sheet or table in the Excel source.
so, how can I resolve this !?
Thanks.

I tried all the available versions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The version of ACE and the version of Excel Re often entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

On my experience if your excel file extension is ".xlsx" and your 32-bit ACE OLE DB data provider installed you can choose 2007-2010 version from Excel Connection Manager. Download 32-bit ACE OLE DB data provider and check the result.
You can find detailed answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896901/ssis-excel-connection-manager-failed-to-connect-to-the-source)